# How can i get card info along customer data? Magento2

Tags: magento2

I get informational cards, but I need to show it to the customer, for example, to show a specific product, name, price, and the customer which bought this product.
Getting cart info

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
  {

     public function __construct(

    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,

    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,

    array $data = []

   )

   {

    $this->cart = $cart;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);

   }

   public function getCartInfo()
   {

    return $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

   }

 }
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
 $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
     echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
      echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
       echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
       echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
      echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
  }

  /* get customer details */

$customer=$cart->getQuote()->getCustomer();
$Customerid = $customer->getId();
$Customeremail = $customer->getEmail();
$Customer_firstname = $customer->getFirstname();
$Customer_lastname = $customer->getLastname();
```

Comment: How can i get customer name or id for each cart information ?

Comment: I need to get Customer (name or id )with his cart info

Comment: In backend, thanks for answer

Comment: Check my updated code. I have added getting customer details

Comment: what were you get an error?

Comment: I did not receive an error, I get empty,  I was not mark your answer as not correct

Comment: Did not you able to get any values or customer values only?

Comment: I can get data only with getQuote()->getItemsCollection(), others give an empty, thank you for your attention

Comment: $customer=$cart->getQuote()->getCustomer();. You can get customer details only for logged in user, otherwise, you can able to get customer details. It's not a bad answer. Kindly check with logged in user. it works fine

Comment: Did you try with logged in a customer?

Comment: Thank you , it's work  $customer=$cart->getQuote()->getCustomer();